# Shell variable gets modified in 'while' loop, but not in 'find | while' loop

Tags: shell, loops, zsh

I have written a zsh script to find some files, loop through and process them.
Once it's over, I need to know some state set by a flag inside the loop.
But the modified value of the flag does not get reflected outside the while loop.

So I tried the loop without the find. This time, the modified value of flag persists outside the loop also.

Thanks for an explanation and a workaround for this.

**'find | while' loop**

```
flag=false
find . -name "*.sh" | while read line
do
    # check conditions, process the file 
    echo "flag = $flag"
    flag=true
    echo "flag = $flag"
done

echo "flag = $flag"
```

**Output**

```
flag = false
flag = true
flag = false
```

**Simple while loop**

```
i=1
flag=false
while [ $i -le 1 ] 
do
        echo "flag = $flag"
        (( i++ ))
        flag=true
        echo "flag = $flag"
done

echo "flag = $flag"
```

**Output**

```
flag = false
flag = true
flag = true
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, however, how `zsh` decides when to execute part of a pipeline in a subshell. `echo foo | read bar; echo $bar` displays `foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the shebang (#!) to the top of your script.  It will run the script in it's own shell.

NOTE: I had eight .sh files in the directory I used it in.

```
#! /bin/zsh
flag=0
echo "Before: flag = $flag"
find . -name "*.sh" | while read line
do
  # check conditions, process the file 
  flag=$(($flag+1))
  echo "Inside: flag = $flag"
done
echo "After : flag = $flag"
```

output:

```
Before: flag = 0
Inside: flag = 1
Inside: flag = 2
Inside: flag = 3
Inside: flag = 4
Inside: flag = 5
Inside: flag = 6
Inside: flag = 7
Inside: flag = 8
After : flag = 8
```

Hope this helps.